# scipy optimizer set up

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I came up with a simpler dummy example for my scenario, can probably solve my example mathematically instead of using an optimizer, but let's preface with, I have to use an optimizer. Sorry if too verbose.

I have this function, that will give me a result based on two lists, a list of weights and a list of factors.

```
def validate_vector(vector, factors):
    return sum([x * y for x, y in zip(vector, factors)])
```

I have a starting point of 3 elements, but then I introduce a fourth element.

```
initial_vector_weights = [.2, .3, .5]
initial_factors = [.09, .07, .01]

new_element_in_vector_weights = [.2, .3, .5, 0]
new_element_factors = [.09, .07, .01, .2]
```

Any time a new element gets added, I will initially add it at a weight of zero, and then I need to validate and make sure the result of my validation is above a threshold of .05. If it is, I keep the new element at a 0 weight.

```
validate_weights(new_element_in_vector_weights, new_element_factors)
0.044
```

This new addition results in a validation below .05, so I can't keep the new element at 0, it must be given a weight such that my validation is .05. I need to optimize for a solution where abs(validate_weights(new_element_in_vector_weights, new_element_factors) - .05) = 0.

I have some constraints, all weights must be positive, and must sum up to 1.

```
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x})
```

I also have an additional constraint, I have to optimize in a way that will increase the new element weight (the new 4th one) from 0, but decrease my initial weights in a manner in which they are proportional to the initial ones.

For example, this could be a solution from my example

```
[.2, .3, .5, 0]
[.18, .27, .45, .1]
```

where old / new is a constant ratio, .2/.18 = .3/.27 = .45/.5 and I am above .05.

```
validate_weights([.18, .27, .45, .1], [.09, .07, .01, .2])
0.059600000000000014
```

However, I want the weight for the 4th element that gets me to exactly .05.

I am trying to do it like this, but this doesn't work.

#### This just makes sure my weights are proportional to the original.

```
def calculate_proportional_weights(original_vector_weights, new_element_weight):
    remaining_weight = 1 - new_element_weight
    proportional_weights = [x * (1-new_element_weight) for x in original_vector_weights[:(len(original_vector_weights) - 1)]]
    return proportional_weights

def prorated_weights_cons(original_weights, new_weights):
    original_weights_core = original_weights[:len(original_weights) - 1]
    new_weights_core = new_weights[:len(new_weights) -1]
    H_new_weight = new_weights[-1]
    redistributed_weights = calculate_proportional_weights(original_weights, H_new_weight)
    return sum(redistributed_weights) + H_new_weight - 1
```

#### This is the function I want to minimize.

```
def min_validate_weights_objective(vector, factors):
    validation_ = validate_vector(vector, factors)
    val_to_min = abs(validation, .05)
    return val_to_min
```

#### This is the optimizer.

```
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': prorated_weights_cons(new_element_in_vector_weights, new_element_factors)}, 
 {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x})

res = minimize(min_validate_weights_objective, new_element_in_vector_weights, args=[new_element_in_vector_weights, new_element_factors], method='SLSQP',constraints=cons, 
              options={'disp': False, 'ftol': .0000000001, 'eps' : .0000000001, 'maxiter':10000})
```

This bombs out with, though I'm sure there are other things wrong with it.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Do you guys see anything egregiously incorrect on this set up? Thank you so much!

Comment: You question is full of isolated code snippets.  That can be useful when you are explaining the code, but it would be useful to also include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can be copied directly from the question and run without having to edit anything.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error message, always include the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback).  It includes useful information, including the line that generated the error.

Comment: The Python function `abs` does not accept two arguments, so the line `val_to_min = abs(validation, .05)` will not work.